# Wrapping an accessor method for a global object in some other function

Tags: php, function, object

I do a lot of stuff specifically with PHP and WordPress, and I've come across this concept quite often throughout the WordPress application; although, this question isn't specific to WordPress. I'll demonstrate with an example.

Say there is some global object of a class.

```
global $foo;
$foo = new Foo();
```

And then this class has some sort of accessor method that could be used with our global object.

```
global $foo;
$bar = $foo->get_bar();
```

Well, often I see this wrapped in a general function that takes care of tapping into the object's method, essentially hiding that part of it, making it more simple to access that item.

```
function wp_get_bar() {
    global $foo;
    return $foo->get_bar();
}
```

And so a developer using the application could just do this where ever they wanted without knowing about the $foo global object specifically:

```
$bar = wp_get_bar();
```

I'm just curious if this is a general computer science concept? If so, is there a name for it? Or is this something I can read more about somewhere?

Comment: Yes, this is called bad programming.

Comment: WordPress' code base is a steaming pile of monkey dung.  None of its code should be emulated.

Comment: I imagine that is there for backwards compatibility. Most of wordpress code was written using functions. It's possible that the devs changed the implementation of that function but kept an alias so it was still available to theme developers.

Comment: haha @moonwave99's comment cracked me up, as it was posted almost instantly when the question went up. -- But yeah, I'd agree with andreshernandez. Looking at anything in WP I can understand from the outside perspective would be horrible to take much away from in learning just because so many hands of touched it, and it's been around so long with all that time it having a strong emphasis on backwards compatibility. I think probably any code base with this kind history could become a "steaming pile of monkey dung."

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question; no there is no official term for accessing variables via global construct within functions, unofficial? How about "Way not to do it".

With that being said, the same thing can be accomplished, properly, using a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern:

```
class Foo {

    protected $bar;

    public function setBar($bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

class Foo_Package
{
    public static $foo;
}

function functionOne($params)
{
    var_dump(Foo_Package::$foo->getBar());
}

function functionTwo($id)
{
    var_dump(Foo_Package::$foo->getBar());
}

Foo_Package::$foo = new Foo();

$foo->setBar('Hi I\'m Bar!');

Foo_Package::$foo = $foo;

functionOne(array('id' => 1));

functionTwo(1);
```

Comment: Meh, not a huge fan of DI. Better yet Observer pattern. Was trying to give a pattern closer to what he was describing.

Answer (score 0):

When Wordpress was created, OOP wasn't very popular. In fact, OOP became more serious with PHP5, and Wordpress started with... PHP3?

In addition, I think that to make it easy for newbie users, Wordpress developers opted using procedural functions instead of objects and classes. It's simpler if you don't have a deep knowledge of WP core.

I don't think this has an specific name.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo for the answer. I can definitely see how WordPress wouldn't be a good example to look at, seeing as they have such a strong emphasis on backwards compatibility and it's been around so long.